# Converting integers to bytes - how does the calculation work

Tags: python, byte, calculation

I am trying to use Python bytes methods to convert integers to bytes.
I know there are different approaches to do this in Python, but  I would like to do this using just the bytes method, which requires to understand how this is done using basic calculation.
As an example I have a function that converts integers to single byte:

```
def int_to_byte(b):
    if b > 0 or b < 255:
        return bytes([b])
```

Above function is easy since this converts a int between 0 and 255 to a single byte.
But I also would like to have following functions which converts a int to two bytes and to four bytes.

```
def int_to_2bytes(b):
    if b > 0 or b < 65335:
        return bytes([b2, b1])
```

Note that b2 and b1 needs to be within 0 to 255 only.
For example if I want to convert 3000 to 2 bytes using the above function I can do something like this:

```
def int_to_2bytes(b):
    if b > 0 or b < 65335:
        return bytes([b//256, b-(b//256*256)])

int_to_2bytes(3000)
b'\x0b\xb8'
```

The above gives me the correct output.

But I am now stuck what calculations to to put in to convert integers to get output as 4 bytes - something like this:

```
def int_to_4bytes(b):
    if b > 0 or b < 4294967295:
        return bytes([b3, b2, b1, b0])
```

How do I calculate b3, b2, b1 and b0 so that these fall within the range of 0 to 255 which then bytes method will return 4 byte back.

I would like to do this using bytes method only, I know I can do this using the struct.pack or something like this: (3000).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big').

Instead of using struct or to_bytes, I would like to know how I can calculate this myself using bytes method.

I manage to also solve using the following Python function:

```
def int_to_bytes(b):
    result = []
    while b > 0:
        tmp = divmod(b, 256)
        result.insert(0, tmp[1])
        b = tmp[0]
    return bytes(result)
```

Any help will be appreciated on this.

Comment: ypou have to use `for`-loop and create `b0 = value % 256` and `rest = value // 255` (and `data.insert(0, b0)`) and later repeat it for `rest` - `b1 = rest % 256` and `rest = rest // 256`, (and `data.insert(0, b1)`), etc. It can be simpler If you use `b` instead of `b0`, `b1`, etc. and at start you set `value = rest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do similar to calculation on paper.

You have to loop and get modulo 256, and divide by 256, and repeat it on result.

```
def int_to_bytes(val):
    data = []
    while val > 0:
        b = val % 256
        val = val // 256
        data.insert(0, b)
    return bytes(data)

print( int_to_bytes(127) )        # b'\x7f'
print( int_to_bytes(3000) )       # b'\x0b\xb8'
print( int_to_bytes(985983) )     # b'\x0f\x0b\x7f'
print( int_to_bytes(184553088) )  # b'\x0b\x00\x0e\x80'
```

---

**EDIT:**

Similar code you can use to convert to other systems, 8, 2, etc.

Using `2` instead of `256` you can get bits

```
def int_to_bits(val):
    data = []
    while val > 0:
        b = val % 2
        val = val // 2
        char = chr(ord('0') + b)
        data.insert(0, char)
    return ''.join(data)

print( int_to_bits(127) )        # 1111111
print( int_to_bits(3000) )       # 101110111000
print( int_to_bits(985983) )     # 11110000101101111111
print( int_to_bits(184553088) )  # 1011000000000000111010000000
```

And exactly the same for `8`

```
def int_to_octals(val):
    data = []
    while val > 0:
        b = val % 8
        val = val // 8
        char = chr(ord('0') + b)
        data.insert(0, char)
    return ''.join(data)

print( int_to_octals(127) )        # 177
print( int_to_octals(3000) )       # 5670
print( int_to_octals(985983) )     # 3605577
print( int_to_octals(184553088) )  # 1300007200
```

For values bigger than `10` it can be simpler to use list with digits

```
    digit = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    char = digit[b]
```

```
def int_to_hexs(val):
    digit = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    data = []
    while val > 0:
        b = val % 16
        val = val // 16
        char = digit[b]
        data.insert(0, char)
    return ''.join(data)

print( int_to_hexs(127) )        # 7F
print( int_to_hexs(3000) )       # BB8
print( int_to_hexs(985983) )     # F0B7F
print( int_to_hexs(184553088) )  # B000E80
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also manage to solve this using your method but replaced to operations with divmod() function within Python.

Comment: similar code you can use to convert to any system - 8, 2, etc. I added code which converts to bits.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned above :

```
def int_to_2bytes(b):
    if b > 0 or b < 65335: # if b > 0 and b <= 65335: (corrected) 
        return bytes([b//256, b-(b//256*256)])
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
def int_to_2bytes(b):
    if b > 0 and b < 256**2:
        return bytes([(b//256**1)-(b//256**2*256),
                      (b//256**0)-(b//256**1*256)])
```

For `int_to4bytes` :

```
def int_to_4bytes(b):
    if b > 0 and b < 256**4:
        return bytes([(b//256**3)-(b//256**4*256),
                      (b//256**2)-(b//256**3*256),
                      (b//256**1)-(b//256**2*256),
                      (b//256**0)-(b//256**1*256)])
```

Following the same pattern, for `int_to_nbytes` :

```
def int_to_nbytes(b, n):
    if b > 0 and b < 256**n:
        return bytes([b//256**(n-1-i) - b//256**(n-i)*256 for i in range(n)])


print(int_to_nbytes(3000, 4)) # b'\x00\x00\x0b\xb8'
print(int_to_nbytes(3000, 8)) # b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\xb8'
```